# Best practices for C project git submodule building

Tags: c, git, git-submodules, autotools

I have a C project using autotools and make to build my project. I need to use code that as far as I can tell is only available on github. What is the best practice for including this code in my project? How would I do it?

[This is the code I want to use](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/secp256k1)

Comment: This question is too broad. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask . However, you probably want to add it as a git submodule will make the source show as a subdirectory of your parent project. You can then add the directory to your Makefile.am.

Comment: I updated my response, you might be interested by it.

Comment: IMO, best practice for submodule is to avoid them like the plague.  If you have a dependency on a library, install the library using actual package management tools rather than trying to use your vcs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I can think of is to probably use [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules) so that you bundle your dependencies with your repository without having them to be inside your repository. This will provide you with 2 advantages, your library dependency will always be (latest), your git repository won't be bloated of all the unnecessary data and objects that the library would have brought.  Make sure to build with the lib and to query the user if he does not have it on his system.

C does not have any native dependency manager.

If any tool could do something like you want and for basically anything, you could look into [Conda](https://conda.io/docs/)